# Firebug error: jQuery is not defined - in yii app

Tags: jquery, yii, yii-components

I'm using Yii Framework v1.1.10r3566. I'm noticing in Firebug that the generated code is producing an error. It says "jQuery is not defined" and the line has a function "jQuery(function($)". It is occurring on multiple pages and I believe that it is preventing my zii widgets from operating properly (CJuiDatePicker is not working when previously it had worked). I am not writing any routines using jQuery nor am I including any other javascript library. The generated code on one of the pages that is generating the error is:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="language" content="en" />
<!-- blueprint CSS framework -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/myapp/css/screen.css" media="screen, projection" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/myapp/css/print.css" media="print" />
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/myapp/css/ie.css" media="screen, projection" />
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/myapp/css/main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/myapp/css/form.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myapp/assets/ef86d901/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myapp/assets/ef86d901/jquery.yiiactiveform.js"></script>
<title>myapp - Login</title>
</head>
```

I'm at wits end and haven't a clue why the generated code is producing this error. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: delete everything in assets folder and refresh.

Comment: @MukeshSoni, his **assets** folder is not a *cached* folder, but a folder with **source** files.

Comment: Yii looks for files in the assets folder. If it doesn't find any, they are regenerated. There is no problem at all in deleting them except for a slight time delay.

Comment: go to your assets folder once and check if the files are there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error is usually the result of **jQuery framework** not being installed. It looks like your `jquery.js` is your jQuery framework since you mention your not using any custom markup yourself.

A quick test is to replace this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myapp/assets/ef86d901/jquery.js"></script>
```

With this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note to replace 1.7.2 with your required jQuery version as explained by using Google's hot-linked [API Libraries](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/).

If that solves your issue, then check the path to your **local jQuery file** or consider using **Google's hotlinked API Libaries** which has other benefits you can [read about](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/).

Comment: Thank you very much! That seems to fix the problem. Although, I'm not sure what to do about it in Yii. Also, I now receive $("#profile-form").yiiactiveform is not a function. Do I need to replace other libraries as well?

Comment: It looks like the **Yii Framework v1.1.10r3566** is not installed either. You will need to check the folder path and redownload it. Also, I am not familiar with that script but perhaps it's missing and should be placed above the **Yii** form you are using. Since this problem was fixed, please accept my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should include jquery in all controller/action, to do that, insert this code to Controller.php (most parent of all controller in application)

```
public function beforeAction($action)
   {

      $cs = Yii::app()->clientScript;
      $cs->registerCoreScript('jquery');

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, then I looked into the "`View Source`", there, the `jquery` was loaded from assets and from the "`js`" directory. So I removed the `registerScriptFile('js/jquery');` . Then it was working fine as it loaded `jquery` only from assets.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem, after I'd set components -> assetManager -> linkAssets to true to ensure the "latest" version of assets were being used. I then forgot, and wiped my assets folder, which removed all the original assets!

Handily I was able to revert the originals (version control ftw) and all was restored. Might be useful to others in a similar predicament.